# Почему laravel elixir не сразу отображает изменения в html после проталкивания на сервер?

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-elixir

Всем привет. Есть проект на laravel 5.3 + vue2. Когда вношу изменения на локальной машине, то все изменения (через gulp watch) сразу видны на html странице. Но когда заливаю изменения на vps сервер, то около часа никаких изменений в html не видны, хотя все файлы с изменениями залились правильно. Чистка кеша в браузере не помогает. Видимо это какой то другой кеш, раз через час изменения вступают в силу?

Подскажите, почему так может быть? Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: Это я думаю у вас вьюхи кэшируются, вы делали сингелтон или на каждой страницы свои компоненты ?

Comment: попробуй php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросу более двух лет и он не имеет ответов. Используемое ПО имеет свежие версии.